# Nodejs : Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, node-windows

As i googled, there is don't have answer for below questions, Actually my code was working fine in linux machine. But i got error in windows,

Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\podio>node bin/run  
D:\xampp\htdocs\podio\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:83
            throw e
            ^

Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
\\?\D:\xampp\htdocs\podio\node_modules\node-expat\build\Release\node_expat.node
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at bindings (D:\xampp\htdocs\podio\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\xampp\htdocs\podio\node_modules\node-expat\lib\node-expat.js:4:32)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

Edited :: 2 I have try to reinstall below npm packages, I have getting below errors, maybe this will also happen,

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\podio>npm install bindings or node-expat or xml2json

> node-expat@2.3.16 install D:\xampp\htdocs\podio\node_modules\node-expat
> node-gyp rebuild

D:\xampp\htdocs\podio\node_modules\node-expat>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp
 (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_mo
dules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Warning: Missing input files:
D:\xampp\htdocs\podio\node_modules\node-expat\build\deps\libexpat\..\..\..\deps\
libexpat\version.c
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [D:\xampp\htdocs\podio\node_modules\node-expat\build\b
inding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proces
s.js:219:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\xampp\htdocs\podio\node_modules\node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "xml2json"
npm ERR! node v6.11.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-expat@2.3.16 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.3.16 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-expat
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\xampp\htdocs\podio\npm-debug.log
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look for the environment variable of Xampp

Comment: how can i do that @SantoshSingh

Comment: @SantoshSingh, can you pls check it now, is there any issues affected above code

Comment: run the above command

Comment: npm install -g node-gyp

Comment: node-gyp rebuild

Comment: No use.. Actually i was trying to reinstall from beginning of node_modules, i stuck when "npm install xml2json" and getting above mention error of edit 2.